# How to flush after n records are committed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have configured two datasources in my batch application. One is to read records from database1 and other to write records to database2.

I have used spring batch for batch processing of records. However, after inserting 3 chunks of records , "duplicate key value violates unique constraint" when there is no duplicate key. I have read multiple posts where it was suggested to flush entity manager to remove the cached objects. I am still confused how to achieve that with my current application and does spring batch do not flush after each chunk processing?

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BatchJob{

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    private final WriterRepository writerRepository;

    private final ReaderRepository readerRepository;

    private final BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer;

    @Qualifier("readerDatasource")
    private final HikariDataSource readerDatasource;

    private final HikariDataSource writerDatasource;

    private static final String QUERY_FIND_Reader_Person = "SELECT * FROM person where exists='Y'";

    private static final String QUERY_FIND_Reader_Adderess = "SELECT * from address where exists = 'Y'";

    private static final String QUERY_INSERT_Writer_Person = "INSERT INTO person (person_id,name,exists) VALUES(:personId,:name,:exists)";

    private static final String QUERY_INSERT_Writer_Address = "INSERT INTO address (id,person_id,street,exists)VALUES(:id,:personId,:street,:exist)";

    @Bean
    Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(importPersonDetails())
                .next(importAddressDetails())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    Step importPersonDetails() {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("importPersonDetails")
                .<Person, Person>chunk(500)
                .reader(personItemReader())
                .writer(personWriter())
                .taskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor())
                .listener(new StepListener())
                .build();
    }

    Step importAddressDetails(){
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("importAddressDetails")
                .<Address, Address>chunk(500)
                .reader(addressItemReader())
                .writer(addressWriter())
                .taskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor())
                .listener(new StepListener())
                .build();
    }

    JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> personItemReader() {
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
                .dataSource(readerDatasource)
                .sql(QUERY_FIND_Reader_Person)
                .rowMapper(new PersonRowMapper())
                .name("PersonItemReader")
                .build();
    }

    JdbcCursorItemReader<Address> AddressItemReader() {
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Address>()
                .dataSource(readerDatasource)
                .sql(QUERY_FIND_Reader_Adderess)
                .rowMapper(new AddressRowMapper())
                .name("AddressItemReader")
                .build();
    }

    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(200);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadnamePrefix("My-Batch-Jobs-TaskExecutor ");
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(Boolean.TRUE);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
        log.info("Thread Pool Initialized with min {} and Max {} Pool Size",threadPoolTaskExecutor.getCorePoolSize(),threadPoolTaskExecutor.getMaxPoolSize() );
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }

    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> PersonWriter() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> PersonJdbcBatchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        PersonJdbcBatchItemWriter.setDataSource(writerDatasource);
        PersonJdbcBatchItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Person>());
        PersonJdbcBatchItemWriter.setSql(QUERY_INSERT_Writer_PersonPerson);
        PersonJdbcBatchItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return PersonJdbcBatchItemWriter;
    }

    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Address> AddressWriter() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Address> AddressJdbcBatchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        AddressJdbcBatchItemWriter.setDataSource(writerDatasource);
        AddressJdbcBatchItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Address>());
        AddressJdbcBatchItemWriter.setSql(QUERY_INSERT_Writer_Address);
        AddressJdbcBatchItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return  AddressJdbcBatchItemWriter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "duplicate key value violates unique constraint" when there is no duplicate key`

The code won't throw this exception if there were no duplicates.. So if you have this exception, you do have duplicates.

> I have read multiple posts where it was suggested to flush entity manager to remove the cached objects

According to your config, you are using `JdbcBatchItemWriter` and not `JpaItemWriter`, so I don't understand why we are talking about flushing an entity manager here. The `JdbcBatchItemWriter` does not use an entity manager, it uses a jdbc template to send insert/update statements to your database which will be committed/rolled back when the transaction is done.

You need to make sure you are not inserting duplicates in subsequent chunks.

Comment: I checked multiple times in source DB no duplicate record is there. However, I am seeing that each time already inserted record is tried to be persisted again and with each run same exception comes with different id and not with same id. Any clue why it's behaving like this.